# Erlang - pattern matching predicate

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

To know if particular expression matches specified pattern I can write in erlang something like following:

```
case <expression> of
    <pattern> -> true;
    _ -> false
end
```

For example:

```
case {1, 2, 3} of
    {_, 2, _} -> true;
    _ -> false
end
```

Is there a way to write it in more compact way? Something like:

```
is_match(<pattern>, <expression>)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's no such construct. You could define a macro to do it:

```
-define(is_match(Pattern, Expr), case Expr of Pattern -> true; _ -> false end).
```

Comment: Would it accept patterns with placeholders? Like {_, 2, _}?

Comment: @mkorszun Sure, it could be any pattern. It's a macro, so it's just doing text substitution.

Answer (score 0):

another macro :o) `-define (IS_MATCH(PAT,EXP), catch(PAT = EXP) == EXP end).` with no case, but I am not sure that a catch is better.

Comment: Yeah, I would avoid the catch just because it has unclear overhead implications. A more in-depth analysis of catching might render the point moot, but you know for a fact that the case statement won't have any overhead outside of matching the pattern.

Comment: Also, you have a secondary comparison which would almost certainly negatively impact performance unless it's optimized away (though I don't believe it would be).

Comment: Don't use "old style" catch expressions, i.e., catch <Expr>, for this kind of thing. It will spend effort to build a symbolic stack trace just so that you can discard it again. See http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-November/075928.html for details.

Comment: It is clear that I do not recommend this version, I put it only for fun!

Comment: @RichardC, I read your linked post and learned some interesting things. thanks for the link.